# How to create file from octet-stream with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oracle

I would like to create a file from octet-stream data.

From a OracleDB I get the following data:

`b'_RCFM*=.u0x\x9c\xec\xbb\x05\\\x94M\xdb7\xbc,\x0b,\x8dtI\x08\x82\xa0\x94J\xc7.(\xa14H7HKH\xf7\x12""\  ... \xff\x05o\xe2x2'`

My current python script looks like this:

```
import oracledb

oracledb.init_oracle_client(lib_dir=r"C:\instantclient_21_6")
dsn_tns = oracledb.makedsn('xxx', 3333, service_name='XXX') 
conn = oracledb.connect(user='xxx', password='xxx', dsn=dsn_tns) 

def output_type_handler(cursor, name, default_type, size, precision, scale):
    if default_type == oracledb.DB_TYPE_CLOB:
        return cursor.var(oracledb.DB_TYPE_LONG_RAW, arraysize=cursor.arraysize)
    if default_type == oracledb.DB_TYPE_BLOB:
        return cursor.var(oracledb.DB_TYPE_LONG_RAW, arraysize=cursor.arraysize)
    else:
        return cursor.var(oracledb.DB_TYPE_LONG_RAW, arraysize=cursor.arraysize)

conn.outputtypehandler = output_type_handler

c = conn.cursor()
c.execute(''' SELECT "DATA"
FROM "ZITSMSCHUL" . "SYSATTACHMEM1" 
WHERE "TOPIC" ='IM28588' ''') 

res = c.fetchall()

strRes = str(res)

strRes = strRes[2:-3]

filePath = 'C:/Users/123/Desktop/37505_ping.doc'
with open(filePath, 'w+b') as f: 
    f.write(bytearray(strRes,encoding='utf-8'))
    f.close()

c.close()
conn.close()
```

This code gives me a .doc file but with the octet stream as content and not the original data.

I'm thankful for any help

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51868112/blob-data-from-oracle-to-text-file-using-python

Comment: To start with, your type handler return type for the CLOB case looks 'wrong', see the example in https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/lob_data.html#fetching-lobs-as-strings-and-bytes which returns `DB_TYPE_LONG` for this case.  But since you're using python-oracledb, you can simply set the new attribute `oracledb.defaults.fetch_lobs = False` and remove the handler.  However hopefully you are storing the binary in a BLOB, so the issue may be on the Python side - there are plenty of Stack Overflow posts about writing to files you can review.